# pass simple parameter to angular ui-bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I see many posts about posting many complicated things to ui-bootstrap modals, but I just want to pass a simple parameter so that I might use it to display different content in the dialog.

For example, I have the main document which has `MyDocumentController as mydoc`

In `MyDocumentController` is a function such as

```
_this.modals = {
    inviteUser: function() {
      $modal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'modules/templates/modals/modal-invite-user.html',
        controller: 'UserInviteModalController as invite',
        size: 'lg'
      });
    }, ...
```

And I call it in the main document like so, here is where I want to pass the param from:

```
<a href="" ng-click="users.modals.inviteUser(returningUser)">
```

And here is the controller for the modal:

```
    (function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('mymodule')
    .controller('UserInviteModalController', function($log, $modalInstance, toastr) {

      var _this = this;

      _this.someVar = HERE'S WHERE I WANT TO GET THE VALUE returningUser FROM THE NG-CLICK

      _this.inviteDialog = {
        close: function() {
          $modalInstance.close();
        },
        resendInvite: function() {
          toastr.success('A new invite has been sent.');
          $modalInstance.close();
        }
      };

    });
})();
```

What is the process for passing the simple param to the dialog's controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `resolve`:

```
_this.modals = {
  inviteUser: function(returningUser) {
    $modal.open({
      animation: true,
      templateUrl: 'modules/templates/modals/modal-invite-user.html',
      controller: 'UserInviteModalController as invite',
      size: 'lg',
      resolve: {
        returningUser: function() {
          return returningUser;
        }
      }
    });
  }, ...
```

And then inject it into your controller:

```
angular.module('mymodule')
.controller('UserInviteModalController', function($log, $modalInstance, toastr, returningUser) {
    var _this = this;

    _this.someVar = returningUser;
```